# How to load PDF file inside HTML?

Tags: html, pdf, html5-canvas

CODE1:

```
 <iframe id="frame" src="document.pdf"></iframe>
```

CODE2:

```
 <embed id="frame" src="document.pdf"></embed >
```

CODE3:

```
 <object data="document.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

I have used the above codes to load PDF file in HTML. It's working correctly in Chrome browser but not working in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

It works fine with Firefox, Opera and Chrome. But Rendering in IE seems to have some issues.